# webview.executeJavascript is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

While starting to sort my js files in a recent Electron project I stopped being able to `webview.executeJavascript` `webview` being a variable that is a querySelector on my webview.

I tried testing to see if it getting the webview from the DOM and it is, all I did was move the code that worked perfectly into a module and now `executeJavascript` Is no longer a function.

If anybody knows the reason or has a clue whats wrong that'd be helpful!

Comment: Is it possible you could include the code of your module and if possible the code before it stopped working?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TukHmV30 And the module was simply loaded with `var bar = require('./file.js')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `webview` was not enabled?

> By default the `webview` tag is disabled in Electron >= 5. You need to
>   enable the tag by setting the webviewTag `webPreferences` option when
>   constructing your BrowserWindow.

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    webviewTag: true
  }
})
```

Source: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/breaking-changes.md#new-browserwindow-webpreferences-

Answer (score 1):

I somehow missed the fact that you can't use `webview.executeJavascript()` the second the Javascript has loaded and needs to wait a bit... It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `executeJavaScript` with a capital `S` ?

Documentation : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture